# Ubuntu linux-headers-generic and lot of dependencies error

Tags: apt, 16.04, dpkg

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. After some updates, if I try to install something I get the error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
10 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/11.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: error processing package libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-4.4.0-34 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-4.4.0-34-generic:
 linux-headers-4.4.0-34-generic depends on linux-headers-4.4.0-34; however:
  Package linux-headers-4.4.0-34 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-4.4.0-34-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic:
 linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-4.4.0-34-generic; however:
  Package linux-headers-4.4.0-34-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 4.4.0.34.36); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 4.4.0.34.36); however:
  Package linux-headers-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processingNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                  No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                           package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: error processing package linux-libc-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-image-4.4.0-34-generic (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-image-generic:
 linux-signed-image-generic depends on linux-signed-image-4.4.0-34-generic; however:
  Package linux-signed-image-4.4.0-34-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-generic:
 linux-signed-generic depends on linux-signed-image-generic (= 4.4.0.34.36); however:
  Package linux-signed-image-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-signed-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 4.4.0.34.36); however:
  Package linux-headers-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libcurl3-gnutls:amd64
 linux-image-generic
 linux-headers-4.4.0-34
 linux-headers-4.4.0-34-generic
 linux-headers-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-libc-dev:amd64
 linux-signed-image-4.4.0-34-generic
 linux-signed-image-generic
 linux-signed-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Even if I try to reinstall the suggested packages I get the same error. Some thing is really messed up. Can you please look into this?

While I was fixing this I also got the error: 
`E: The package linux-headers-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.`

And earlier today it was asking for root password, but I never configured one.

[image: Ubuntu asking root password]
[image: sources.list sources.list.d]

Comment: Yes, you can go ahead and tell me to reinstall my system :(

Comment: did you try 'sudo apt-get clean' to remove broken packages?

Comment: @ridgy I tried it. It does nothing and when i try to do `sudo apt-get upgrade` I have same errors

Comment: How about `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: @Arronical Thanks but it gives the same error. :(

Comment: Maybe your apt sources are broken (see: 'I can't find an archive for it'). Please check your '/etc/apt/sources.list' and files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d.

Comment: @ridgy Thanks that might be the problem. I am attaching another file for the output of both sources.list and sources.list.d. Please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: @ridgy is the shell output I have attached ok?

Comment: at a first look it seems OK to me. What does `sudo apt-get update`say? (please do not attach screenshots from console output, as they are very hard to read; rather cut and paste)

Comment: @ridgy it was too long for comment so heres the gist link:
[gist link](https://gist.github.com/shafaq/78449677d153b30a3394654de839d132)

Comment: @ridgy here is the gist for /etc/apt/sources.list output
[gist for /etc/apt](https://gist.github.com/shafaq/349df4a3dfc76aeb9d6d442d9481cf05)

Comment: This is annoying. I've never seen those 'In Release' messages when doing apt-get update. Please try to comment the uncommented lines in those files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d (add a '#' at the beginning of the line) or rename them to e.g. google-chrome.list.xx etc. (only those ending in .list). Maybe you may even delete them, if the content of the .list and the .list.save are equal. Then try again `apt-get update`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43697/discussion-between-ridgy-and-shafaq).

Comment: Ok everyone I had to reinstall my computer. /usr partition was full.